# How can I find $\Im(\log(1-e^{inx}))$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm aware that $$\Im(\log(1-e^{inx}))=\arg(1-e^{inx})=\arctan\left(\frac{\Im(1-e^{inx})}{\Re(1-e^{inx})}\right)=-\arctan \left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{1-\cos(nx)}\right)$$

but how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your steps are correct, note that $$\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{1-\cos(nx)}=\dfrac{2\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\cos(\frac{nx}{2})}{2\sin^2({\frac{nx}{2}})} = \cot\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{nx}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Comment: No problem. You're welcome!